# Does IE 6.0 support maintaining the session when opening a new browser using a link?

Tags: hyperlink, internet-explorer-6

I have a page on which is a link. This link opens a second page (on the same server/application) in a new window. The second page uses Session variables.

My application works fine with IE 9.0 that I have but it has to work with IE 6.0 as well.

My concern is it may loose session with IE 6.0; not 100% sure.

How could I test my app with IE 6.0? is it possible to install IE 6.0 with IE 9.0 side by side?

I'm using IETester tool but it doesn't support popup window scenarios.

Any thoughts?

Thanks,

Comment: How is the ID of the session communicated back to the server?

Comment: http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=11575

Comment: perhaps using a sessionId cookie.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I happen to have one of those Virtual PC images thirtydot mentioned.

Just tried it to be sure and YES, session is carried across links.

However I do remember a bug from a long long time ago which related to pop-ups opened from modal dialogs which DO NOT carry forward session - it was a known IE bug at the time.